# Dynamically inserting Html tags in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to dynamically insert HTML tags in wordpress. I using the code below to get all the terms in a custom taxonomy colour and it works fine:

PHP:

```
$terms = get_terms("colour");
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
 echo "<ul>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

 }
 echo "</ul>";
}
```

However I want the Html to be rendered to be as follows:

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="Cream"/> Cream </label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="White"/> White </label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="Yellow"/> Yellow </label>
```

Please help in how i can achieve this?

Comment: Er, echo lables and inputs instead of li's?? Did you actually try anything before posting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$terms = get_terms("colour");
   if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
   $html = '';
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     $html .=  '<label><input type="checkbox" rel="' . $term->name .'"/> '.$term->name.' </label>';

    }
  echo $html;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = get_terms("colour");
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo '<label><input type="checkbox" rel="'.$term->name.'"/> '.$term->name.' </label>';
 }
}
```

Comment: Also, I would add that the `rel` attribute doesn't exist for input. I'm assuming the OP meant `data-rel`. I would suggest to the OP to read up on [more info about data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)